# The second time i press record button, my app crashes

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my code snippet.

```
private fun record() {                                                          

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)                      
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)              
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)                
    val path: File = filesDir                                                  
    try {                                                                      
        tempFile = File.createTempFile("audioTemp", ".3gp", path)              
    } catch (e: IOException) {                                                  
        Log.d("recording error", "recording error:", e)                        
    } catch (e: FileAlreadyExistsException) {                                  
        Log.d("File already Exist", e.toString())                              
    }                                                                          

    recorder.setOutputFile(tempFile?.absolutePath)                              
    try {                                                                      
        recorder.prepare()                                                      
    } catch (e: IOException) {                                                  
        Log.d("recording error", "recording error:", e)                        
    }                                                                          
    recorder.start()                                                            
}                                                                              

private fun stopRecord() {                                                      
    recorder.stop()                                                            
    recorder.release()                                                          
    button_play_sample.isEnabled = true                                        
    button_record.isEnabled = true                                              
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this)                                        
    try {                                                                      
        player.setDataSource(tempFile?.absolutePath)                            
    } catch (e: IOException) {                                                  
        Log.d("stop recording error", "Stop Recording Error:", e)              
    }                                                                          
    try {                                                                      
        player.prepare()                                                        
    } catch (e: IOException) {                                                  
        Log.d("recording error", "recording error:", e)                        
    }                                                                          
}                                                                              

private fun play() {                                                            
    player.start()                                                              
    button_record.isEnabled = false                                            
}                                                                              

override fun onCompletion(mp: MediaPlayer?) {                                  
    handler = Handler()                                                        
    handler?.postDelayed({button_record.isEnabled = true}, 1000)                
}
```

I cant figure out why but I have a record button that records audio. When the activity first loads, the recording loads. When I press it the second time because I don't like my first recording, instead of overwriting the old file and setting up record again, App crashes instead.

Comment: App crashes then what is the *error* in *logcat* ? Post it here.

Comment: Post the error which is showing in logcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder?authuser=3), it says

> When you are done with the MediaRecorder instance free its resources
>   as soon as possible by calling release().

see this [sample code](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder?authuser=3#sample-code) from the Developer site:

```
private void stopRecording() {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;
}
```

Your code snippet doesn't check if `recorder` is being used.  You might want to do that before using the `MediaRecorder` object again.

```
private fun record() {
    if (recording) {
        stopRecording()
    }

    // do recording snippet here...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I figured it out too. after releasing the recorder. I have to null it or else I'll have multiple instances every time I press the record button. Same with the player apparently. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: btw, you need to instantiate `recorder = new MediaRecorder()` inside `record()`



```private fun record() {                                                          
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
//code .....```

Comment: @FranCeriu he didn't posted initialisation code, i assume it's outside his `record()` function.  Maybe somewhere in `onCreate`? just maybe.

Comment: @chip yeah you're right. if he will use/invoke the `record()` again, he will get nullpointerexception.

Comment: @FranCeriu its `IllegalStateException`, i think, not NPE